Quartz.Net context.Scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs() and Interrupt() not retrieving the active running jobs
In Quart.NET, v3.81, I have an issue where basically when a job starts at the same time, we're talking 10 to 50 miliseconds here, as I'm trying to interrupt it, Quartz doesn't recognize that it started and therefore doesn't interrupt it.
Unfortuantely I can't reproduce this issue every time, but I do reproduce it every once in a while.
Has someone ever reproduced this issue ? if so I'm curious on what solution you found.
The solution I've found is pretty dirty but working
                    if (await context.Scheduler.Interrupt(currentJobDetail.Key, _cancellationTokenSource.Token))
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation($"{task.Name} is pending cancellation before instance update 1");
                        continue;
                    }

                    var currentJobTrigger = context.Scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(currentJobDetail.Key).Result.First();

                    var currentTimeUtc = (DateTimeOffset)DateTime.UtcNow;
                    var previousFireTimeUTC = currentJobTrigger.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc();

                    if (previousFireTimeUTC != null)
                    {
                        if ((currentTimeUtc - previousFireTimeUTC).Value.Seconds <= 1)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(1000);

                            if (await context.Scheduler.Interrupt(currentJobDetail.Key, _cancellationTokenSource.Token))
                            {
                                _logger.LogInformation($"{task.Name} is pending cancellation before instance update 2");
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }

